# User in Administrators group can't access files via smbclient

Tags: windows, permissions

I created a user ("backupagent") on a laptop running Windows 7 Home Premium, and added that user to the Administrators group, with a randomly-generated, difficult-to-guess password.  My plan is to log into the machine over SMB to back up the files on the laptop (actually, BackupPC is doing this, but I can't seem to get this to work with smbclient on its own either).

I set up a windows share ("cback") on the laptop sharing the entire C: drive, and allowed backupagent all permissions on the share ("Read" / "Modify" / "Full Control").

When I log into the machine from my Linux box using "smbclient", I am able to access much of the filesystem, except for files under the "C:\Users\UserName" folder, which are of course the most important ones to back up.  When I attempt to list the files in any directories contained in C:\Users\UserName, I get an error:

```
  smb: \Users\UserName\Desktop\> ls
  NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \Users\UserName\Desktop\*
```

Why is backupagent (a member of the Administrators group) unable to access these files?  Windows permissions have always been completely bewildering to me...

Answer (score 1):

At first there is no need to create any additional shares on the box. There is administrative share for drive c: - \\hostname\c$. Every user in Admin group is able to access it. 
Another thing is that two "types" of permissions are in regards to the shares. First one is "share" itself. It is just who can access the share and who can connect to the share. And another one is NTFS ACLs. These are the main point of security configuration. NTFS permissions could be found on "Security" tab on folder properties.
So in general you need to set Everyone "full control"  for share permissions and granually grant permissions using NTFS ACLs. 
In your particular case you need to check NTFS ACls on the files and folders you are trying to access.